# Ограничение ресурсов для ssh-сессий

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, openvz

Привет! Есть openvz-контейнер с centos 6 на борту. К этому контейнеру по ssh цепляются юзеры для того чтоб послушать трафик tcpdump'ом, посмотреть лог с помощью tail/less и т.п. и иногда случается такое, что они оставляют запущеный, например, дамп в своей сессии и он утекает по памяти из-за чего OOM-killer начинает отстреливать всё подряд. Я могу написать скрипт который бы следил за этим и отстреливал такие процессы

```
tcpdump=`ps -o pid,etime= -C tcpdump | grep -P "^[0-9]{4,}\s+[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}$" | cut -d " " -f1`;if [ $tcpdump ]; then kill -9 $tcpdump; fi;
```

Но мне кажется это не тру вэй. Я слышал краем уха, что можно задать лимиты с помощью cgroups - так ли это? Просто ли это делается? Можно ли какой-то рабочий пример? Или может это с помощью чего-то другого делается?
Заранее спасибо!